# What does "off the strip" mean (Las Vegas)?

Tags: meaning

> We went to a restaurant that was a little bit off the strip (about Las Vegas)

I found in Wiki that Strip is the place where most Las Vegas casinos are. So what would such sentence mean?

- Restaurant was very good as it is close to the best(?) location in the city
- Restaurant was in sketchy neighborhood
- Nothing about being good/bad, just a location

Comment: A wild guess : a restaurant which is far away from strip club :) That would be so Las-Vegasish.

Comment: @tugberk - Actually, the strip clubs in Vegas are located... off the Strip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of those options, I would choose the third - nothing about good/bad, just a location.
"The Strip" is the southern part of Las Vegas Boulevard; over the past couple of decades or so, it has grown further and further south, so that now it extends several miles outside the actual city limit.  If you are arriving from the airport or via highway from Los Angeles, the Strip is the first thing you see (and it can be hard to remember that there's anything else there at all!)

I don't have hard data for this, but I would guess that over 90% of visitors to Vegas never leave the Strip; this means that real estate just off the Strip is much cheaper, but that off-Strip business owners must either work much harder to bring in the tourist crowd, or concentrate on building a clientele among local residents.  Off-Strip restaurants, therefore, tend to be much like local restaurants everywhere else; if you go to Vegas expecting to eat at a celebrity chef's restaurant, you'll have to stay on-Strip.

There certainly are some sketchy neighborhoods in Vegas (or just outside it), but they tend to be several miles from the Strip; generally the term "off-Strip" means **just** off the Strip, rather than far away from it.

Comment: Just to clarify - by "much like local restaurants everywhere else" I don't mean that off-Strip restaurants are necessarily not good!  There are indeed some fantastic places... but they'll never become famous, because on-Strip you have Thomas Keller, Wolfgang Puck, Mario Batali, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It just means the restaurant was not located in the very popular region, but somewhere a little bit farther away, so that it is quieter.

It's the third option: Nothing about good/bad, just a location.

Comment: So in quiet location then?

Comment: so my comment is nearly true :)

Comment: Yes, nearly...:):), ever been to Las Vegas?

Answer (score 3):

"Off the Strip" means out of the *general area* of Las Vegas Boulevard - which is a little over 4 miles long.

I say general area, because it's not just the blvd itself (between Russell and Sahara) which constitutes 'the strip' - that area is defined by the Nevada Gaming Commission. If I recall correctly, the Hard Rock Casino and some other properties are on Paradise (which is east of the blvd), but are also considered part of 'the strip'.

Being 'off the strip' doesn't mean it's sketchy or less attractive (although it could be), it is merely out of the area defined by the NGC.  Thus, property prices are lower, etc because it's not considered 'prime strip property'.